# How to Copy file in Server page with out reading

Tags: java, android

Friends.,
 I get some file from android device i want to save that file to my web server without reading that file(it may be mp3,mp4,mpeg format) I use Struts2(Java) in my web server how can i do that...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Your android device has to read the file through an InputStream, to send it to your server. Your server has to read that Stream an write it whereever you want.

But you can't send a file without open/reding from it.

Your Server can't read Files from the device. You have to read it within your android device.